# Rails devise gem: force logout on browser-tab close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise gem,

if I close the browser or the browser-tab and I open it againg the session remains active.

How I can force logging out users on browser close?

Comment: A file, session_store.rb should be in your Config/initializers directory. It is the file where you specify how long you want a session to last. Can you please check it and see if you can understand and adjust it yourself otherwise post it here for help.

Answer (score 0):

remove **rememberable** property from model file.

Answer (score 0):

**Browser Tab Close:**
The session cookie is per-process not per window. So even if you selected New Window you'd still get the same session id. This behavior makes sense. You wouldn't want a user to re-sign in each time they opened a new window while browsing your site.

**Browser Close:**
You can not 'force' the client to close a session, since closing a session is an action that the client must request from the server (eg: by logging out).

Therefore, typically sessions have a time-out period that is checked regularly. Each session has a 'start time' stored in the database, and sessions that are too old are purged.

That said, there may be some way in javascript to detect a browser close event and make some best-effort attempt to close the session. But there is no guarantee - the user can always forcefully kill the browser process, leaving the server totally in the dark.

In short, you can't rely on the client to close a session. A timeout is probably your best option.